# Display to table fetched JSON values in a different format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I currently have a table which displays data like so:

http://snag.gy/fyO48.jpg

I have a service which fetches the data from an SQL server and encodes it into a json. My problem is the json is structured like so:

http://snag.gy/TqZly.jpg

count_reqs should be put in the corresponding column. For example, the first row data should be displayed as such:

`http://snag.gy/tB0ji.jpg  <--- cant post more links sorry`

How can this be done?

Here's my code for the table:

```
<table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tower</th>
                    <th>Job Level</th>
                    <th ng-repeat='data in dataset.headers'>{{ data }}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat='tower in dataset.dataByTower' ng-init='current = 0'>
                    <td rowspan='{{ tower.entries.length }}'>{{ tower.tower_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ tower.job_level }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: The best way to get an answer here is to create a fiddle. There are some unclear areas in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tower</th>
                <th>Job Level</th>
                <th ng-repeat='data in dataset.headers'>{{ data }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='tower in dataset.dataByTower' ng-init='current = 0'>
                <td rowspan='{{ tower.entries.length }}'>{{ tower.tower_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ tower.job_level }}</td>
                <td ng-repeat='data in dataset.headers'><span ng-if="data ==tower.year_month">{{ tower.count_reqs}}</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

P.S. I'm not tested this, because you don't provide **jsFiddle** or data of your `dataset.headers` and `dataset.dataByTower`.